# How to replace part of text in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I update and replace part of string/text in SQL?

I want to be able to update my `Article` table, and substitute all of `&#8217;` with `'` in `Description` field. How can something like this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE Article 
SET Description  = REPLACE(Description , '&#8217;', '''')
```

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'&#8217;','''')`

Comment: Modified Query after Goat Co's comment

Answer (score 0):

TRY this out.

```
UPDATE Article
set Description = replace(Description, '&#8217;','''')
```

Comment: This will throw an error, I think. Your UPDATE syntax has extra `TABLE` key word in it and your replacement value is a and empty string `''` and an extra single quote `'`.it should be `''''`

Comment: the user wanted it to be single qoute as per his requirements. please see the question once

Comment: `Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '')`

To get a single quote, you need `''''` in the third parameter of the `REPLACE()` function.

Comment: @M.Ali its okay, i am here to learn. the more i get to critic the more i learn . Thank you.